# Get reference of the viewcontroller from where pageviewcontroller is created programmatically

Tags: ios, xcode, swift4, uipageviewcontroller, ios12

I have created pageViewController programmatically from a BaseViewController as -

```
class BaseViewViewController : UIViewController {
        func viewDidLoad() {
            let viewControllers = [ViewController1, ViewController2, ViewController3]
            let pageController = UIPageViewController(transitionStyle: UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyle.scroll, navigationOrientation: UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientation.horizontal, options: nil)
            pageController.setViewControllers(viewcontrollers, direction: UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection.reverse, animated: false, completion: {(_) -> Void in
                    }) 
        self.addChildViewController(pageController)
    }
}
```

Now, being in ViewController1, I want to access the reference of the BaseViewController. 
But I am able to get only pageViewController's reference as -

```
let pageViewController = self.parent
```

inside ViewController1; I need to access the BaseViewController instance.
Any suggestions on these are appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a couple ways to go about it.

1. Try the parent of the parent (grandparent)

   ```
   let pageViewController = self.parent
   let baseViewController = pageViewController.parent
   ```
2. Set a property on your ViewController1, ViewController2, etc classes to reference BaseViewController.

Comment: First way give me nil value and  second way also gives me wrong value as I want to retrieve a property value from the BaseViewController, and not for passing the value to it.